# Floating Point Exception When Inserting Into Hash Table

Tags: c++, hashtable

Hello I am having an error that is killing me.

I have a vector bucketVector that is a vector of lists of pairs

```
std::vector <std::list<std::pair<K, V> > >  bucketVector;
```

This is my hash table and my insert function causes a floating point exception when I try to insert into a hash table of strings. (K and V are the key and value data types).

```
bool HashTable<K, V>::insert(const std::pair<K, V> & kv) {

    auto & whichList = bucketVector[myhash(kv.first)];

    //if( find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), kv ) != end( whichList ) )
        //return false;

    whichList.push_back( kv );
     if( ++currentSize > whichList.size( ) )
        rehash( );


     return true;
}
```

The hash function:

```
size_t HashTable<K, V>::myhash(const K &k) const {

    std::hash<K> makehash;


    return makehash(k) % bucketVector.size();

}
```

However, trying to insert the string pair "bob dole" into the table causes a floating point exception after the line

```
auto & whichList = bucketVector[myhash(kv.first)];
```

in the insert function.

EDIT:
As someone pointed out, the size is zero on the first insert which results in a floating point exception. However, replacing the myhash return line with just a constant such as 5 results in a segmentation fault

Comment: Could it be that `bucketVector.size()` returns 0?

Comment: Okay yes, it actually is becaus eon the first insert the vector is empty. So I have no idea how to handle that within the hash function. But for now, I've replaced the line with simply return 5; in the hash function, and this results in a segmentation fault

Comment: Your vector is empty. Accessing any index will give you either an exception or a segfault. You have to resize the vector first and then assign the hash functions value range to the buckets of your vector.

Comment: Yes I was using reserve() in my constructor when I should have been using resize. This issue is resolved now thank you!